# In C, How can I restrict the accepted values that this scanf will take?

Tags: c, scanf

I'd like to restrict the possible values that the following `patient_id` variable can have(for security reasons). The following is the code I currently have, but I'm pretty sure this is the wrong approach:

```
   void addPatient(){
           int patient_id;
           printf("Enter ID between 10000 & 99999: ");           
           do{
           scanf("%d", &patient_id);
           }while((patient_id<10000)&&(patient_id>99999));

    }
```

Comment: `patient_id<99999` should be read `patient_id>99999` ? Apart from that, your solution seems fine, there is no way to restrict input range for integer using scanf. You can't even prevent a string to be input when you request an integer.

Comment: Did you mean `while((patient_id>10000)&&(patient_id<99999));` ? Otherwise the first condition is superfluous as `10000 < 99999`.

Comment: @hmjd The other way around :)

Comment: The wrong thing I guess would be what lOranger suggest and also maybe some prompt asking the user again and again to input a value in the required range.

Comment: @hmjd - Hmm yea wait It's ||  - (patient_id<10000) ||(patient_id>99999)

Comment: My friends! That's like, a side issue right?!! I was curious about restricting values safely..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're writing a program for homework problem, and in particular if you're writing a program that an actual human user will interact with in any serious way, **don't use scanf()**.  Operate on *lines of input* at a time.  If you still want to use scanf()'s 'parsing', you can use sscanf() and like on a complete line of input after you have it.  If you don't know how to get user input other than through scanf(), a simple way is to fgets() into a buffer, pick out the line, and prepare the buffer for the next fgets().

If you insist on using scanf(), I have a challenge for you: use it to accept two IDs on the same line, separated by a space.  If the user enters only one ID and then hits enter, your program should complain about this to the user before requesting any more input.

Answer (score 2):

your condition should be

```
while((patient_id < 10000) || (patient_id > 99999))
```

for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

This code should restrict the value the patient_id should have.
This is not the most efficient way by far, but it if you want to use scanf(), then this can do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int patient_id(void);

int main(void)
{
 int id=0;
 id = patient_id();

 printf("\nThe patient_id is: %d\n", id);
}

int patient_id(void)
{
    int p_id;
    int ch;

    printf("Enter ID between 10000 & 99999: ");
    scanf("%d", &p_id);

    while ((p_id <10000 || p_id >99999))
        {
            while((ch = getchar()) !='\n')
               continue;

            printf("Please enter a value between 10000 and 99999:  ");
            scanf("%d", &p_id);
        }
    return p_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) The check you're using is correct; .*scanf doesn't know integer range restrictions.

(2) As other posters noted, scanf() does not beget good user interfaces. Use readline() to get lines and sscanf to parse them and you'll be happier.

(3) You're restricting these values for security purposes? If this is actually a security issue, those should ***not*** be magic numbers but #defines or static consts or globals, so that if somebody changes those ranges without updating your code your security check isn't compromised.

Answer (score 1):

You can not contol input values while accepting these values. You have to first accept values and then you can check condition whether the input accepted is correct or not. You can generate a warning for wrong inputs.

In above code if you want `patient_id` between 10000 to 99999, then your code is correct, but user will enter values till he/she enters a correct input.

eg.
   1, 200124, 45, 9999, 321, **12001**.
Here your prgm will stop accepting input as user enters 12001.